# Using regExp/regEx in a for loop to make a string of specific chars.

Tags: javascript, regex, string, for-loop

Not sure if this is possible (or at least not how I'm trying to do it), but the basic idea is that I'm looking to use a for loop and regExp to knock out special characters and return all alphanumerics and white space in a new string. If I change 're' in the for loop to an indiivudal letter (ex. "C") it will return the C, so I'm 90% sure it's how I've got regExp set up?

I've checked out MDN and S.O. and haven't found anything that does this, but also nothing that says it can't work...

```
function nothingSpecial(str) {
  var re = '/[A-Z]\s/gi';
  var newStr = '';
  for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    if (str[i] === re){
      newStr = newStr + str[i];
      console.log(newStr);
    }
  }
    if(str.length <= 0) {
    return ("Not a string!");
  }
}


nothingSpecial("%^Ca234n'345t f9i9g8r93\ \i!t! !#o$u#t(#(&nt")
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1) Your pattern matches 2 chars while you pass just 1, I think you wanted to use `var re = /[A-Z\s]/i;`. 2) to check if a string matches a regex, use `RegExp#test(String)` and do not use `/g` modifier then.

Comment: Is the expected result `Cant figr it outnt`? Why not use `str.replace(/[^A-Z\s]+/gi, "")` to remove all non letters and non-whitespace?

Comment: I was just trying to use a for loop to make it work. No reason other than to see what for loops were capable of and to figure out how regExp worked/how to use it outside of the method you gave.  *Thank you though the snippet str.replace -I also couldn't figure out how to get the " " to stay)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 3 issues:

1) When defining a regex literal, do not use it inside single/double quotes (that will make it a string literal)

2) Your pattern matches 2 chars while you pass just 1 to it. I think you wanted to use `var re = /[A-Z\s]/i;` to match a char that is either an ASCII letter or whitespace.

3) To check if a string matches a regex, use `RegExp#test(String)` and do not use `/g` modifier in this case.

Note that you'd better check the input (if it is a string or not) at the very beginning.

```js
function nothingSpecial(str) {
  if(str.length <= 0) {
    return ("Not a string!");
  }
  var re = /[A-Z\s]/i;
  var newStr = '';
  for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
    if (re.test(str[i])){
      newStr = newStr + str[i];
    }
  }
  return newStr;
}

console.log(
  nothingSpecial("%^Ca234n'345t f9i9g8r93\ \i!t! !#o$u#t(#(&nt")
);
```

However, to get what you need you may just use

```js
console.log("%^Ca234n'345t f9i9g8r93\ \i!t! !#o$u#t(#(&nt".replace(/[^A-Z\s]+/gi, ""))
```

The `/[^A-Z\s]+/gi` regex will match one or more (`+`) characters other than (as `[^...]` is a negated character class) ASCII letters and whitespace.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a reason to .test instead of .match?  On MDN .match seemed like a good option with regEx.

Comment: `String#match()` returns an array of results or null while `RegExp#test()` returns a boolean result. Usually, people use them interchangeably, but if you need true or false, why collect match results in the first place (if you do not need them)? Thus, a little overhead is avoided.

Answer (score 0):

1)
You just use the below code to get the things done:

```
var str = "%^Ca234n\'345t f9i9g8r93\ \i!t! !#o$u#t(#(&nt";
var finalData = str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");    
alert(finalData);//output: Cant figr it outnt
```

2)
A work around:

```
var str = "%^Ca234n\'345t f9i9g8r93\ \i!t! !#o$u#t(#(&nt";
    var final_str = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (filtered_string(str.charCodeAt(i))) {
            var tmp = str[i];
            final_str += tmp;
        }
    }
    alert(final_str);// Output: Ca234n345t f9i9g8r93 it outnt
    function filtered_string(strCode) {
        if (strCode >= 48 && strCode <= 57 || //Digits 0-9
            strCode >= 65 && strCode <= 90 || //Alphabets caps
            strCode >= 97 && strCode <= 122 || //Alphabets lower case
            strCode == 32){ // space
            return strCode;
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
```

Comment: The question is tagged JavaScript.

Comment: yeah, I'm trying to see what other way it could be done. For instance, if .replace couldn't be used (why I don't know, but play along with me here) then what do you do...